# Personalized message in the cart by product category to encourage you to continue shopping

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

With the following code I can display a message in the cart to encourage users to continue buying more products, but the message appears permanently for all product categories, how can I make it work for one or more specific categories? Thanks for what you can help me.

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_table', 'woo_add_continue_shopping_button_to_cart_products' );

function woo_add_continue_shopping_button_to_cart_products() {

 echo '<div class="woocommerce-message">';
 echo ' <a href="https://midomain.com/" class="button">Continue Shopping →</a> Do you want more products?';
 echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: _“how can I make it work for one or more specific categories”_ - loop over the current cart content, check what categories the products belong to, and then make your decision based on that …? You are not even specific here, what _exactly_ you want - show it only when _only_ products from those categories are in the cart, or at least one of them, or …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array of the categories for which you want to show the 'Keep shopping' link, and an array of all categories currently in the cart. You can then use `array_intersect()` to see if there are any matches between the two arrays. If so, show the link:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_table', 'woo_add_continue_shopping_button_to_cart_products' );
function woo_add_continue_shopping_button_to_cart_products() {

    // Define categories which should show the keep shopping link
    $keep_shopping = array( 'Music', 'Clothing' );

    // Check categories in the cart
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $terms = get_the_terms( $cart_item['product_id'], 'product_cat' );
        if ( !empty($terms) ) {
            foreach ($terms as $key => $term) {
                $order_cats[$term->term_id] = $term->name;
            }
        }
    }

    // Get array of category matches
    $cat_matches = array_intersect( $keep_shopping, $order_cats );
    if ( count( $cat_matches ) > 0 ) {
        // 1 or more matches, show keep shopping link
        printf( '<div class="woocommerce-message"><a href="%s" class="button">Continue Shopping →</a> Do you want more products?</div>', get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: I implemented your code with one of my categories, but it doesn't work, it doesn't show any messages. ¿It is possible to customize the follow button to redirect you to a custom URL?

Comment: I’ve tested this and it works on my end. Are you sure you’ve added the correct category name(s) to the $keep_shopping array? And that the items in the cart belong to one or more of the categories?

Comment: I have done everything correctly according to what you indicate and it does not show the message.

Comment: Could you add some items to the cart. Then add `echo "<pre>"; var_dump( $order_cats ); echo "</pre>"; die();` after the foreach loop. And reload the cart page. That should display an array of the categories in the cart. The values you'll find there will have to match with what you add to the `$keep_shopping` array.

Comment: show me that. `array(25) {
  [54]=>
  string(10) "Accesorios"
  [80]=>
  string(8) "Bandanas"
  [88]=> `

Comment: I can only see 2 of the 25 categories that were returned, but that is enough. Remove the line of code after the foreach loop I've sent, and make sure your cart has the same items in it. And change the `$keep_shopping` array to: `$keep_shopping = array( 'Accesorios', 'Bandanas' );`

Comment: what happens is that it was not including the sub categories so it did not work, now it does. But do you know why it doesn't work for virtual products?

Comment: Subcategories should also be included in the `$order_cats` array. And there is no specific reason why this wouldn't work for virtual products. Since this is the answer to your question could you mark it as accepted, and possibly upvote? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you @Terminator-Barbapapa